# Converting an excel field with multiple units of measure into one

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel imported data field that comes in with multiple units of measure. I need to convert that into a single unit of measure.

Data field example:  "7 gal 45.2 fl oz"

I need to convert that into the total number of gallons - the answer of 7.353125 gallons.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy single function to convert such complex units. Excel sees this data simple as text and is unable to enact any maths on it in its current state. You have to first separate the numbers out of the text, then apply the conversion formula yourself on each number and combine.

**Split numbers from text**

The easy way to separate the numbers is to select the column and click Data > Text to Columns. Select "Delimited", and check "Space" as delimiter and check if the columns are correctly shown in the preview. Format each column appropriately as text or value. You could add additional delimiters such as a tab or comma.

**Tips**

- make sure you have enough empty columns to the right in order to not overwrite other data
- If you have inconsistent data where the numbers are in different order, say "7 gal 45.2 fl oz" and below it "USD 1", the columns won't be only numbers or only text. This isn't a big problem, but it might make you life easier to e.g. first "search and replace" all "USD" with "" or "-1 USD".

**CONVERT the numbers**

You can now use the numbers in formula e.g. say A1 contains 7, B1 "gal", C1 45.2, D1 "fl" and E1 "oz". In F1 put

```
=A1 + C1/128
```

If you don't want to hard code the conversion formula, the [CONVERT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-function-d785bef1-808e-4aac-bdcd-666c810f9af2) function could come in handy:

```
=A1 + CONVERT(C1,"oz","gal")
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use flash fill!**

Say you have the data like this, then manually type in the first row the numerical data you want in the adjacent cells:

[image]

Select the cell with the "7", and click Data > Flash Fill (Data Tools group) or CTRL+E. Do the same for "42.3".

[image]

**Flash-to-formula:** (next level flash fill)

You can combine everything into one cell, then use search and replace to turn the cell into a working formula. Manually type in the first row the numerical *formula* like you want it in the adjacent cell (but start with a **<kbd>`</kbd>**):

[image]

Select the empty cell below it and click Data > Flash Fill (Data Tools group) or CTRL+E.

[image]

Double-check the data and correct only the first error (like in B2 in my example where the first number wasn't correctly picked up). As soon as you correct one mistake, Excel will immediately fix the rest:

[image]

Finally hit **<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>**, click the replace tab, and replace all **<kbd>`</kbd>** with **<kbd>=</kbd>**. Your calculations will be complete.